# Is there a way to show less service logs in console in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Now when I'm running my app using `docker-compose up` i get in console lot of logs from mongoDb

[image: screen from terminal]

I want to get only "web" service related logs for my information as logs from mongo are unreadable and useless for me in development.

I tried using

```
command: --quiet
logs:
    driver: none
```

And didn't get quite the result i was hoping for.
I want all the docker starting logs describing what is going on while staring but then none of the mongo health raports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the best solution was adding file

```
#mongod.conf
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
```

and in docker-compose

```
#docker-compose.yml
mongo:
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
      - ./mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Start docker-compose in detached mode and bind the logs of your app to stdout:

```
    docker-compose up -d
    docker ps
    docker logs [YOUR_CONTAINER_ID] --follow
```